# (KIVY) Using accordion as a side menu

Tags: accordion, kivy

So I am trying to make a side menu with accordion, and have a carousel with text input beside it. But, the accordion stays open. I want it to start closed, then upon click it opens, then click the accordion and it closes again. But how?
Here's my code:

```
BoxLayout:
    padding: 0, 40
    id: spacetext
    Accordion:
        size_hint_x: .8
        AccordionItem:
            title: 'All your Notes'
            Label:
                text: 'List of notes'

    Carousel:
        loop: False
        #size_hint_x: .85
        ScrollView:
            id: scrlv
            size_hint_x: 1
            TextInput:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: max(self.minimum_height, scrlv.height)
        ScrollView:
            id: scrlv
            size_hint_x: 1
            TextInput:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: max(self.minimum_height, scrlv.height)

        ScrollView:
            id: scrlv
            size_hint_x: 1
            TextInput:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: max(self.minimum_height, scrlv.height)

        ScrollView:
            id: scrlv
            size_hint_x: 1
            TextInput:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: max(self.minimum_height, scrlv.height)
```

Only for kivy language, I have the python too but as of now it does not use this.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the [NavigationDrawer](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.navigationdrawer) widget from the [kivy garden](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.garden.html). You can put the accordion in the drawer, and manually toggle the opening and closing.

Comment: If I were to package it, would it be a dependency or does it get packaged in the package? (I'm not even sure how the packaging works yet)

Comment: It's just a python file, you can package it with everything else easily. The garden tools have an option to install it locally in the app folder, which makes this even easier.